# How to creat a function to return an array with 21 waypoints separated

Tags: javascript, directions

i want to creat an array with 3 positions containing 21 waypoints..~
for that i need a function like this : 
my default array its : waypt2 = [Array(22), Array(22), Array(17)]

```
function work_waypoints(waypt2){
    waypts.push({
      location: waypt2[i][g].latlgn,
      stopover: true // obrigatório paragem
    });
    return waypts;
  }
```

Comment: Which waypoints should go to which position?

Comment: What are your input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do here. For what I understood, maybe you can try something like this for the arrays content:

```
Array.from(
  { length: 21 },
  (_, index) => ({
    stopover: true,
    location: object[index] // ...
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below code generate way points with random integers as positions,

> 

```js
function generateWaypoints(){
  console.log(Array.from({length: 3}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)));
}

Function.prototype.sequence = function(from, to) {
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) this.call(null, i);
};

generateWaypoints.sequence(0, 21);
```